# Reading data inserted into Google Fit API through HistoryAPI

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm developing Google Fit API application and last 2 days I've been  trying to store and retrieve data belongs to the BPM data type in different android  applications. Meanwhile retrieving it returns zero points, although meanwhile inserting framework reports that everyting is inserted. I created OAuth keys for both applications, each of them has a subscription to this data type. Also I use enableServerQueries() for retrieval.

Datasource is being created as

```
daataSource=new DataSource.Builder().setName("measurementsSource").setDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM).
                            setAppPackageName(getApplicationContext())
                            .setType(TYPE_RAW).build();
```

Does anyone has any ideas how to fetch data in a proper way?

Upd. According to the advice, I've added full code to add 1 point of custom DataType which I'd like to use. I've tried it number of times, but it still says 'ok' and no data could be available for getting back (for example, with API explorer).

```html
package test.com.cloudydiscoverer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataPoint;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataSet;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataSource;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Field;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataTypeCreateRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DataTypeResult;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
import static com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataSource.TYPE_RAW;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;
    private static boolean authInProgress = false;
    protected GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = null;
    private GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks connectionCallbacks = null;

    private void buildFitnessClient() {
        GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this);

        builder.addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API);
        builder.addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API);
        builder.addApi(Fitness.BLE_API);
        builder.addApi(Fitness.SESSIONS_API);
        builder.addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API);
        builder.addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API);

        builder.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE));            //TODO; verify scopes
        builder.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE));
        builder.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE));
        builder.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE));

        googleApiClient = builder.build();
    }

    public boolean flag=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        connectionCallbacks = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

               /* try {
                    Thread.sleep(120000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
*/
                DataTypeCreateRequest request = new DataTypeCreateRequest.Builder()
                        .setName("test.com.cloudydiscoverer.cloudy_s")
                        .addField("value", Field.FORMAT_INT32)
                        .build();

                Fitness.ConfigApi.createCustomDataType(googleApiClient, request)
                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataTypeResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(@NonNull DataTypeResult dataTypeResult) {

                                if (!dataTypeResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "DataType creation/retrieval failed with result: " + dataTypeResult.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                                } else {

                                    Log.i(TAG, "created");

                                    DataSource wSource=new DataSource.Builder().setName(dataTypeResult.getDataType().getName()+".source").setDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM).
                                            setType(TYPE_RAW).setAppPackageName("test.com.cloudydiscoverer").build();
                                  /*  DataSource wetSource = new DataSource.Builder()
                                            .setDataType(dataTypeResult.getDataType())
                                            .build();*/

                                    DataPoint b = DataPoint.create(wSource);
                                    b.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                                   b.setFloatValues(5.0f);
                                    //b.getValue(dataTypeResult.getDataType().getFields().get(0)).setInt(42);

                                    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(wSource);
                                    dataSet.add(b);


                                    Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(googleApiClient, dataSet).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                                                                                                  @Override
                                                                                                                  public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                                                                                                                      Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(status.isSuccess()));
                                                                                                                  }
                                                                                                              }
                                    );


                                }
                            }
                        });
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network is unavailable. " +
                            "Connection will be restored automatically.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service has been disconnected. " +
                            "Connection will be restored automatically.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };


        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener onConnectionFailedListener = new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed with result: " + result.getErrorCode());

                if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                    return;
                }
                if (!authInProgress) {
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You need to authorize.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        authInProgress = true;
                        result.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_OAUTH);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception has been caught.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        };


        Log.i("1","1");
        buildFitnessClient();
        googleApiClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks);
        googleApiClient.registerConnectionFailedListener(onConnectionFailedListener);


        Log.i("2","2");
        googleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
            authInProgress = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if ((!googleApiClient.isConnected()) || (!googleApiClient.isConnecting()))
                    googleApiClient.connect();
            } else {

                Log.i(TAG, "Nothing could be done.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think its easy to understand the issue with the code you printed. It would be better if you post more details on how your are inserting and reading the fit data

Comment: @SuryaChaitanya, thank you, I've edit my question.